# Перенаправления на сайте и использование ЧПУ

Tags: php, .htaccess, шаблоны, редирект

Ситуация в следующем, создал htaccess с необходимыми настройками, но забавная ситуация стала с отображением: если стоит контроллер, то все отображается, добавляю action и пропадают изображения.Хотя контроллер отрабатывает так как переменные подставляются, но нет изображений. Не могу понять в какую сторону копать, так как даже сформулировать проблему не получается.
Надеюсь на помощь. Также почему-то в шаблоне перестала работать логика. Ниже будет фото и код...

если просто home контроллер отрабатывает, но не работает логика в шаблоне
[image: отрабатывает]

А если ставить слеш или добавить действие index, то результат следующий
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**файл htaccess:**

```
# Включаем модуль переписывания URL
RewriteEngine On

# Путь до корня сайта
RewriteBase /

# Исключить ситуации с существующими файлами и папками
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Перенаправление
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0
```

**файл index:**

```
/*
 * получаем начальные настройки кодировок,
 * переменные с путями скриптов ($pathRoot,$pathBD, $pathConfigs)
 * */
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .
    'protected/configs/initial_setup/setup.php';
session_start();

// Разбираем URL на параметры, 1-й контроллер, 2-й action
// например /articles/edit
$urlinfo = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$urlparts = explode('/', $urlinfo);

$params = [];

foreach ($urlparts as $v) {
    if ($v != 'index.php' && $v != '') {
        $params[] = $v;
    }
}

// извлекаем из массива параметров контроллер
$controller = isset($params[0]) ? array_shift($params) : 'index';

// извлекаем из массива параметров action
$action = isset($params[0]) ? array_shift($params) : 'index';

// Динамически формируем контроллер
$controller = 'C_' . ucfirst($controller);
// Формируем action
$action = 'action_' . $action;

// Контроллер по-умолчанию
if (!class_exists($controller)) {
    $controller = 'C_Home';
}

$controllerObj = new $controller();
$controllerObj->Request($action, $params);
```

**код из header, где перестала работать логика:**

```
<div class="row justify-content-end align-items-center">
                <?php echo "авторизация=".$authorization ?>
                <?php if (!$authorization): ?>
                    <img src="/protected/m/img/user.png"
                         alt="logo">
                    <button type="button" class="btn
                btn-outline-dark">Регистрация
                    </button>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <img class="user-img" src="<?= PATH_BD_IMG.$fotoUser ?>" alt="">
                    <button type="button"
                            class="btn btn-outline-success"><?= $login ?></button>
                    <a href="/"><img src="/protected/m/img/user_exit.png"
                                     alt="logo"></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: Откройте инструменты разработчика в браузере на вкладе сеть и посмотрите куда действительно у вас уходят запросы к картинкам.

Comment: В том то и дело, что адреса одинаковые

Comment: Здесь в коде они еще не были заменены на константы, а вот где были константы там были проблемы, сначала поменял константы, но тогда перестали пути в php работать, поэтому и решил просто слешей наставить, а так спасибо за помощь. (<img class="user-img" src="/<?= PATH_DB_IMG . $fotoUser ?>" alt="">)-----(define("PATH_CONFIGS",   'protected/configs/');
define("PATH_MODEL",   "protected/m/");) Это для примера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что при смене адреса в браузере меняется место вызова картинки.
 А так как в HTML вызов отсчитывается от того места где вызвали основной файл, то адреса теряются.

РЕШЕНИЕ: добавил перед адресами слеш и заработало. Одно не удобно у меня пути в константы прописаны, а для php и html приходится по разному их использовать.

Проблема с авторизацией решилась в процессе сама, т.к. необходима была переменная.

Comment: Судя по вашему представленному коду, слеш у вас там изначально стоял.